# What is the basic architecture of a node.js + mongodb app?

Tags: mongodb, node.js

I've been looking for ages with no luck. I found some modules on GitHub but unfortunately, were outdated. Does anyone know any CRUD module or tutorial for node.js 0.6.x + mongodb?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291130/is-there-a-crud-generator-for-mongoose-and-node-js-and-underscore-or-a-crud-gen - NodeJS, Nginx and Oracle. MongoDB I have not used.

Comment: wt... 9 answers out of 10 I find on SO are closed as off topic too broad or whatever. I can smell an upcoming fail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try node mongodb native driver for it; [node-mongodb-native](https://github.com/christkv/node-mongodb-native)

Sample insert ;

```
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
var server = new mongodb.Server("127.0.0.1", 27017, {});
new mongodb.Db('test', server, {}).open(function (error, client) {
  if (error) throw error;
  var collection = new mongodb.Collection(client, 'test_collection');
  collection.insert({hello: 'world'}, {safe:true},
                    function(err, objects) {
    if (err) console.warn(err.message);
    if (err && err.message.indexOf('E11000 ') !== -1) {
      // this _id was already inserted in the database
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: does it have CRUD out of the box or it just facilitates the process?

Comment: @ylerdurden Sorry, I'm kind of beginner on this. What's the part in the docs that are involved in the CRUD operations and how should I use them?

Comment: see the insert, update, find and Find and modify section.. It supports all basic mongo shell commands with same syntax, as you can see both javascript syntax.. See edited answer for basic insert

Answer (score -1):

## Basic architecture of a node.js/express + mongodb CRUD service

node.js/express apps allow you to easily create URL-specific HTTP request handlers, so it's very convient for making a simple service API.  There are two basic parts to this: routing, and handling.

### Request routing

For a mongodb CRUD service, one approach is to implement it as a REST API with a URL scheme that specifies the CRUD operation, target db, and collection in the URL.
`/[crud]/{db}/{collection}`
To CREATE a document in *myMongo*, in *myCollection*, just send a POST request to 'http://host/c/myMongo/myCollection', with the document in the request body.  The node router object allows regex-based path matching and term extraction.  So the following:
`router.post(/\/c\/(\w+)\/(\w+)$/, require('./create'));`
would match the CREATE request, add the two terms for the db and collection to the request object (see below), and send it to the handler defined in *create.js*.

### Request handling

The request handlers take the form:
`function(req, res, next)` where
***req*** is the incoming request object (and, also, where the URL path terms that were matched prior will be be placed)
***res*** is the outgoing response object
***next*** is a callback, signaling to continue to the next request handler

Performing the CREATE operation might look something like the following:

```
var d = req.params[0];
var c = req.params[1];
var client = getMongoDBClient();
client.db.db(d).collection(c).insert(req.body);
client.close();
res.end();
```

(The other operations would look similar.)

#### Example

I wrote my own service to handle very simple CRUD operations on mongodb documents. It is implemented as a node.js/express app and uses the node-mongodb-native driver. I didn't really intend it as a tutorial, but it does cover the basics I described above and might help you get started.

https://github.com/stupid-genius/MongoCRUD

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: It's difficult for me to even attempt to edit the answer if you delete it 3 hours after complaining about it.

Comment: @Allen: You are more than welcome to undelete your answer, once you have edited it with respect to the comments... which is exactly what you've done here, so I'm not sure why the answer being deleted is seen as a problem.