# Node.js - how to write scaffold generator for Express

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, express, code-generation, scaffolding

I want to write my own scaffold generator for Express Framework. I do realize that there are frameworks that do that, but I want to write my own. I'd like the functionality to be similar to Rails.

For example:

```
generate model user name:String email:String
```

should create `user.js` in the models directory, with the two specified fields in the schema.

I also want to generate the controller for the model, with the crud operations using the db connector:

```
generate controller users mongoose
```

should create `users.j`s in the controllers directory and should contain the crud operations based on mongoose api.

How do I go about doing the same?

PS: The back end is a REST API for an IOS app, so I'm not interested in generating views.

Comment: Please try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10692218/node-js-mongoosejs-crud-scaffolding

Answer (score 2):

If you want MVC framework in node js with generator functionalities then my prefer

[CompoundJS](http://compoundjs.com/docs.html)

also routes and syntax are more similar to ruby on rails

You can also do CRUD through it by `compound generate crud post title content`

for controller `compound g controller controllername actionName anotherActionName`

for Model `compound g model user name password createdAt:date activated:boolean`

For Scaffold `compound g scaffold post title content createdAt:date`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you want a scaffolding tool with full model & API & resource support.
You can try this tool:

[Amur](https://github.com/zhangkaiyulw/amur)

With amur, you can create a full-fledged backend server with your complex app logic and running API in less than 3 minutes.

Amur automate backend coding process.

However, it creates graphQL style API, if you can accept that.